# Creating ISO images from DVDs

Tags: iso

I just ordered a set of restore DVDs for a Gateway desktop PC with Windows XP and I'm wondering how to create ISOs of the DVDs just in case the restore disks get lost or thrown away. Is there an easy and quick way to do that without having to download separate software?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/dvd of=dvd.iso
```

A little explanation

sudo makes sure the command is executed as root. That's needed only if the user you're working under doesn't have enough permissions to access the device. But it's ignored if it's not needed so you can just ignore it as well.

- `dd` stands for Disk Dump
- `if` stands for Input File
- `of` stands for Output File